# Как на Python отправить файл напрямую в принтер?

Tags: python, windows, сокет, print

Есть задача отправить файл в принтер через скрипт Python. Но нужно сделать это не системным вызовом, а путем отправки файла в порт принтера. Скажите, каким образом это можно реализовать? В свойствах принтера порт указан как USB001. Нужно ли открывать порт в принтере и как это лучше сделать в windows? И самое главное, какая библиотека мне поможет отправить файл/байт-код напрямую в порт? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [python-cups](https://pypi.org/project/pycups/). Библиотека лёгкая:

```
>>> # Example of getting a list of printers
>>> import cups
>>> conn = cups.Connection ()
>>> printers = conn.getPrinters ()
>>> for printer in printers:
...     print printer, printers[printer]["device-uri"]
...
HP ipp://192.168.1.1:631/printers/HP
duplex ipp://192.168.1.1:631/printers/duplex
HP-LaserJet-6MP ipp://192.168.1.1:631/printers/HP-LaserJet-6MP
EPSON-Stylus-D78 usb://EPSON/Stylus%20D78
```

. Но, честно говоря, я неуверен, что она вам подойдёт. Какая-то уж у вас специфичная задача.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но всё ещё не понимаю - как можно отправить файл напрямую в печать на USB принтер? Как пример, можно взять последний принтер Epson из вашего примера.